# How to avoid duplicate when a user click the "refresh" button of his browser?

Tags: php, html, browser

For example, I ask this question and click "Post your question" and stay in the current page. Now I may click the "refresh" button of my browser to see new answers. But I find that on my website, if I click the "refresh" button, a duplicated question will be published. How to avoid this problem?
I am using PHP.

Comment: How to determine whether data has been submitted?

Comment: How does stackoverflow.com avoid/tackle this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is common practice after a `POST` request, to redirect to the same page to avoid this problem.

Lets say you are on `/ask_question.php`

Your opening `<form>` tag might look like this:

```
<form action="/ask_question.php" method="post">
```

Now, in your `/ask_question.php` do something like this:

```
if( isset($_POST['new-question'])){
    // Do your processing here

    // On success:
    header('Location: /ask_question.php');
    exit(); // End the request
}
```

**Update** *It is important to only redirect after a valid `$_POST` request has been handled. I test for a form field named `new-question` but you should use any form field name that has to be present for the `$_POST` to succeed*

This processes their posted data, then on success, redirects back to the same page. The only difference now, is that when they click refresh, no information will be posted.

**Note** Just make sure nothing is `echo`'ed out prior to the `header` call.

Comment: @Alix haha. However, I got too verbose. Your answer is much shorter and probably communicates the answer better :)

Comment: What does if( isset($_POST['new-question'])) mean? Does it make a difference?

Comment: I updated my answer to further explain that point, but it was my way of showing a test for a valid $_POST request. You can do whatever you want, but just make sure the redirect will only happen after a `$_POST` request, otherwise you will create an endless loop of redirects.

Comment: Do you mean if a user clicks the "refresh" of his web browser,( isset($_POST['new-question'])) will return false?

Comment: Steven, if you follow my code exactly, the user will be "redirected" back to the page. If they then click `refresh` there is no POST data floating around to be submitted again. The request will be a `GET` request and no `POST` data will be sent at all so the `isset` test would return `false`

Answer (score 1):

Submit the form using POST, upon submission validate and if everything is fine **redirect the user** to a success page, that way if the user refreshes the page all he'll do is see the "thank you" page again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use POST for your form. Pretty much every browser will ask the user to confirm when refreshing a POSTed form result, since it has to resubmit it.

Second, in your form processing script, check to see if the question already exists - or set a session for the user and keep track of if they've recently submitted something.

Comment: But my browser(Firefox) doesn't ask me to confirm.