# Please help me out how to submit button value only on button click not on page refresh

Tags: php

I'm using form in a project. In my form, when I click on submit button, the values are submitted properly but after submit if I refresh the page the existing values are inserted again without clicking on button. Please help me out how to submit the button value only on button click not on page refresh.

Comment: Need to include your code here.

Comment: How are you refreshing the page? With code or by clicking refresh? If you refresh a page straight after submitting it, it will resubmit all the data. As far as I'm aware theres no way around that. Even if the fields are empty it will attempt to resubmit.

Comment: I am refreshing the page by clicking refresh

Comment: @Soft-logics:) Means that you're resending the page. In such a case, the browser sends the web page with the current status that does the same action which you have made by clicking the submit button and in such a case I think the users themselves need to be careful.

Comment: Then how can i send button value only on button click....Is this possible or not ?

Comment: after inserting the data on the databases, you need to redirect it on the page you want, example: a view page which contains list of the data you've inserted

Comment: @Lion: **I think the users themselves need to be careful** is a very bad approach. Users never should be trusted. It is the job of the programmer that the application runs smoothly even if the user screws up.

Comment: It's right. Such things must not be left to users but in certain situations, I don't think that there may be a direct way to prevent such kind of things. For example, let's say that I need to perform inert, update and delete operations only on a single page then redirecting to another page after every operation is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use a redirect after page submit to a thank you page.

```
Header('location: thankyou.php');
exit();
```

Comment: That may be unnecessary in certain applications.

Comment: After submit, redirect is a standard practice. Or another way will be submitting with ajax. But i am guessing op is a newbie and above code will do the trick for him.

Answer (score 1):

Use the post-redirect-get pattern. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

This means you use POST method on the form, and in the response script you redirect the user to a different page with the location header.

There is a good answer to your question here: [How to avoid duplicate when a user click the "refresh" button of his browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962832/how-to-avoid-duplicate-when-a-user-click-the-refresh-button-of-his-browser)